# How to put values from a GTM variable array in to a tracking pixel?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is it possible to implement the following tracking pixel through Google Tag Manager:

[image]

...by using the following variable array?:

[image]

```
 [
  {
    id: '4009314961126',
    name: 'Schuurschijf k120',
    price: '4.7900',
    quantity: 1,
    category: 'Gereedschap & Werkplaats/Machine toebehoren/Schuurmachines/Delta-
              &Multibladen',
    brand: ''
  },
  {
    id: '4008496270705',
    name: 'Varta knoopcel CR1216 lithium',
    price: '5.5000',
    quantity: 1,
    category: 'Elektra/Energie/Knoopcellen',
    brand: ''
  }
]
```

**Update #1**
With the help of @Max I was able to create the JavaScript I needed:

```
var pixel_url = "http://gethatch.com/iceleads_rest/merch/91487/direct";
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) { 
    var product = products[i];
    pixel_url += ";ean="+product.id+";cur=EUR;pr="+product.price+";qty="+product.quantity+";vendor_name="+product.brand+";prod_name="+product.name;
}
var pixel = document.createElement("img");
pixel.src = pixel_url;
pixel.height = 0;
pixel.width = 0;
document.body.appendChild(pixel);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ronaldbijker/a3qLc607/51/

Comment: Remarks: if you pasted the array code (instead of the screenshot), it would be easier for people to help. There are plenty of fields in your tracking pixel (mpn, vendor) which don't appear in your array, where do you plan on getting this information from?

Comment: Thanks @Max. I've just added the array code. The field mpn is not required (mpn OR ean is required). Vendor from the tracking pixel = brand from the array. The brand in the array is not filled at the moment but it will be filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

1. Create a dataLayer variable called `{{ecommerce_products}}` which reads ecommerce.products from dataLayer.
2. Create a tag which is triggered on confirmation page with below code
3. Update `pixel_url =` as per your needs

Tag code:

```
var products = {{ecommerce_products}};

for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) { 
    var product = products[i];
    var pixel_url = "http://gethatch.com/...prod_name="+product.name+"qty="+product.quantity+...
    var pixel = document.createElement("img");
    pixel.src = pixel_url;
    document.body.appendChild(pixel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Max! I've created a variable which reads ecommerce.purchase.products from the dataLayer. I've made a few adjustment to de tag code you provided. I've added a working example to my original question.

Comment: @RonaldBijker: glad I could help, nice you posted a full working example